# Magento 2.4.6 search synonyms doesn't work on REST API

Tags: magento2, rest-api, search-criteria, opensearch

I am trying to make use of search synonyms. I have created a synonym group, and added synonyms comma separated, and afterwards ran full re index.

[image]

```
http://website/rest/V1/products?searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=name&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=%25cucumber%25&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][condition_type]=like&searchCriteria[pageSize]=5&searchCriteria[currentPage]=1
```

This is returning data. But if I replace 'cucumber' with the synonyms , if returns no results. I am using open search as my search engine.